# Upload FFmpeg output directly to Amazon S3

Tags: video, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, transcoding

I am using the fluent-ffmpeg library with node.js to transcode videos originally in a flash movie format to the mp3 format with multiple resolutions, 1080p, etc..  Once the transcoding is complete, I would like to move the transcoded video to an s3 bucket.

I pull the original .flv file from a source s3 bucket and pass the stream to the ffmpeg constructor function.  The issue is after the transcoding completes, how do I then get the stream of the mp4 data to send to s3.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
        var params = {
            Bucket: process.env.SOURCE_BUCKET,
            Key: fileName
        };
        s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred

            var format = ffmpeg(data)
            .size('854x480')
            .videoCodec('libx264')
            .format('flv')
            .toFormat('mp4');
            .on('end', function () {
                //Ideally, I would like to do the uploading here

                var params = {
                   Body: //{This is my confusion, how do I get the stream to add here?},
                   Bucket: process.env.TRANSCODED_BUCKET,
                   Key: fileName
                };
                s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {

               });
            })
            .on('error', function (err) {
                console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
            });

        });
```

For the code above, where can I get the transcoded stream to add to the "Body" property of the params object?

Update:

Here is a revision of what I am trying to do:

```
var outputStream: MemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        var proc = ffmpeg(currentStream)
            .size('1920x1080')
            .videoCodec('libx264')
            .format('avi')
            .toFormat('mp4')
            .output(outputStream)
            // setup event handlers
            .on('end', function () {
                uploadFile(outputStream, "").then(function(){
                    resolve();
                })
            })
            .on('error', function (err) {
                console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
            });
```

I would like to avoid copying the file to the local filesystem from s3, rather I would prefer to process the file in memory and upload back to s3 when finished.  Would fluent-ffmpeg allow this scenario?

Answer (score 6):

You don't seem to be saving the output of the transcoding anywhere.

1. Save the output of the transcoding (your new `.flv` file) using [`output`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg#outputtarget-options-add-an-output-to-the-command) to your local filesystem.
2. Provide your new file's contents to `putObject`. According to [the `putObject` documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property), the `Body` parameter accepts:

   > `Body` — (`Buffer`, `Typed Array`, `Blob`, `String`, `ReadableStream`) Object data.

Here's some revised sample code:

```js
// Generate a filename for the `.flv` version
var flvFileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length - path.extname(fileName).length) + '.flv';

// Perform transcoding, save new video to new file name
var format = ffmpeg(data)
    .size('854x480')
    .videoCodec('libx264')
    .format('flv')
    .toFormat('mp4');
    .output(flvFileName)
    .on('end', function () {
        // Provide `ReadableStream` of new video as `Body` for `pubObject`
        var params = {
             Body: fs.createReadStream(flvFileName)
             Bucket: process.env.TRANSCODED_BUCKET,
             Key: flvFileName
        };

        s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {

        });
    })
```

Note: You may be able to create an output stream from `fluent-ffmpeg` and upload that stream to AWS S3, if you prefer, but this will complicate the logic and error handling.

Comment: Is there a way to write to a memory buffer temporarily, then send the buffer in the Body param?

Comment: Is there a way to avoid having to temporarily writing the file to the filesystem?

Comment: See here for a strategy to upload to s3 without writing locally. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54837065/2679757