# Rails 5 - Concurrent large Video uploads and FFMPEG encoding in the background is making the server very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, video-streaming, carrierwave

I have a working Rails 5 apps using Reactjs for frontend and [React dropzone uploader](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/) to upload video files using carrierwave.

**So far, what is working great is listed below -**

1. User can upload videos and videos are encoded based on the selection made by user - [HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) or [MPEG-DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP) for online streaming.
2. Once the video is uploaded on the server, it starts streaming it by:-

   - FIRST,copying video on `/tmp` folder.
   - Running a bash script that uses `ffmpeg` to *transcode* uploaded video using predefined commands to produce new fragments of videos inside `/tmp` folder.
   - Once the background job is done, all the videos are uploaded on AWS S3, which is how the default `carrierwave` works
3. So, when multiple videos are uploaded, they are all copied in /tmp folder and then *transcoded* and eventually uploaded to `S3`.

**My questions, where i am looking some help are listed below -**

1- The above process is good for small videos, **BUT** *what if there are many concurrent users uploading 2GB of videos*? I know this will kill my server as my `/tmp` folder will keep on increasing and consume all the memory, making it to die hard.**How can I allow concurrent videos to upload videos without effecting my server's memory consumption?**

2- Is there a way where I can directly upload the videos on AWS-S3 first, and then **use one more proxy server/child application to encode videos from S3**, download it to the child server, convert it and again upload it to the destination? but this is almost the same but doing it on cloud, where memory consumption can be on-demand but will be not cost-effective.

3- Is there **some easy and cost-effective** way by which I can upload large videos, transcode them and upload it to AWS S3, without effecting my server memory. Am i missing some technical architecture here.

4- How Youtube/Netflix works, I know they do the same thing in a smart way but can someone help me to improve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you say `memory` are you talking about disk? or ram? I think you are misusing the term,

Comment: The disk, to be precise :), but it also effects your RAM, as entire process consumes some part of your RAM to the encoding too.

Comment: The term `memory` is precise. It means ram. Can you update the question please to use the correct terms?

Comment: just restated my question to be more semantic

Comment: `I know this will kill my server as my /tmp folder will keep on increasing and consume all the memory`. Is `/tmp` a RAM disk? If not, It will not consume all the memory.

Comment: yes, so basically, it is a folder within my production server like /apps/vconvertor/tmp where entire code resides

Comment: Ok, so the first question does not make sense then. Because putting a file on disk does not use memory.

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg has some options to connect from a stream, so you can connect to your S3 file directly and process it by small parts and upload as multipart to S3 too you can do this right with the server that you already have or use lambda from AWS as @samuil said

[here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736246/stream-ffmpeg-transcoding-result-to-s3) where they have a simple snippet that could send you in the right direction

```
var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "ffmpeg",
    Arguments = $"-i pipe:0 -y -vn -ar 44100 -ab 192k -f mp3 pipe:1",
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = false,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
};

using (var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo })
{
    // Get a stream to an object stored on S3.
    var s3InputObject = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(new GetObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = "my-bucket",
        Key = "input.wav",
    });

    process.Start();

    // Store the output of ffmpeg directly on S3 in a background thread
    // since I don't 'await'.
    var uploadTask = s3Client.PutObjectAsync(new PutObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = "my-bucket",
        Key = "output.wav",
        InputStream = process.StandardOutput.BaseStream,
    });

    // Feed the S3 input stream into ffmpeg
    await s3Object.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(process.StandardInput.BaseStream);
    process.StandardInput.Close();

    // Wait for FFmpeg to be done
    await uploadTask;

    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One convenient option for doing that would be:

1. Upload files directly to S3 using [presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjectPreSignedURLRubySDK.html)
2. Use AWS Lambda for transcoding, or even better: use [hosted & managed solution](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/) for that.

Concurrent users won't be your limitation: you don't really care about disk OR computational resources here. Spikey traffic will be handled by managed service. While solution running costs might be a bit higher when compared to self-built solution, I doubt it will be cheaper if you factor in infrastructure setup and maintenance costs.

Comment: Thanks @samuii, but I dont want to use any paid service and want to rely on my own scripts to encode videos to HLS/DASH streams.So if we remove the managed solutions part, how would be the flow ? any idea? and where aws lambda will come into picture.?

Comment: S3 isn't free either. You are afraid of running into performance problem. Solving them on your own is hard. AWS Lambda let's you create virtual machine whenever you have a task to perform. In case of transcoding video you could use existing layer (e.g. https://github.com/serverlesspub/ffmpeg-aws-lambda-layer). It is paid service as well.
Creating this kind of solution from scratch is complicated, and needs number of iterations until you get it right. If you haven't done it in the past, I dare to say that it will be cheaper to use existing solution.

Comment: Thanks @Samuii, for the quick reply.Let mw check to see how can all this fit into my use case and then I would love to come back,

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this question considers your limited resources both on machine & money.

Consider using queue for ffmepg encoding script - then you will avoid simultaneous encoding tasks.

Comment: Can you give a practical example of what you suggested?

Comment: @Milind basically when video is uploaded do not encode it directly but put into queue. Have a separate process that consumes queue and processes video one-by-one

Comment: well, its already processed by background jobs by using /temp folder, which copies and encodes it thereby effecting memory, if videos are more than 1.5 GB in size.

Comment: it is not only about processing in background, it is about making this sequential (prevent concurrency on processing)

Answer (score 0):

After trying bunch of options, I was able to come up with a fool-proof and scalable option, by which I am able to upload almost 10GB of video easily, The steps, in concise manner are listed below -

1. No more server side uploading for large videos. Hence Carrierwave is removed.
2. Instead, I employed aws-sdk library to upload directly from the Reactjs Frontend.
3. This involves a single trip back to the server to ensure file(key) is successfully uploaded and then later updates the DB.
4. From AWS's perspective, the chain goes like ->> S3(object created) >> Triggers Lambda Job >> Job fetches object from input bucket and after conversion dumps into output bucket >> also hits the server with Job ID to give it to the backend which is stored in the db(to let users know if video os still processed or not) >> then SNS sends an email to the user.
5. S3 Output bucket is mounted with CloundFront along with Accleration enabled, to allow fast upload(5gb in hardly 1.10 mins).

As there are metadata details of the uploaded content, the backend uses it to serve and update the users accordingly.

All the above was totally inspired and customised based on the existing AWS Video ON demand documentation on Github.
Link is here - https://github.com/aws-solutions/video-on-demand-on-aws

Hope it helps.